# Ajax request results in attempted 302 redirect instead of returning JSON

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using an ajax request on click to trigger a controller `JsonResult` in MVC. When I click, I receive an HTML response instead of JSON, here is my code:

```
$('.platform-list-item').click(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "@Url.Action("PlatformClick", "To")",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "platform": $(this).find(".platform-click").val() }),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("worked!");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

The `$(this).find(".platform-click").val()` is a string value. Here is my controller code in `ToController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PlatformClick(string platform)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("PlatformClick");
    Debug.WriteLine(platform);
    return Json("test");
}
```

Here are the two new events that show up in my Network Tab through Developer tools. Where did I go wrong? Thank you!

[image]

**EDIT**: Adding HTML View per request:

```
<div class="platform-to-container">
    <div id="platform-container">
        <div class="album-container">
            <div class="album-img-container">
                <img crossorigin="anonymous" id="album-img" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-9vhl8uXrclxW-0-t500x500.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="platform-links-container">
            <div class="artist-song">@Model.Album.AlbumName</div>
            <div class="artist-song-container">
                <img class="artist-img" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000438614124-cca9kq-t500x500.jpg" />
                <div class="artist-name">@Model.Artist.ArtistName</div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-list-container">
                @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Album.SpotifyLink))
    {
                <div class="platform-list-item">
                    <div class="platform-logo-container">
                        <img class="platform-logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/unlink/platform-images/music-service_spotify_v3.svg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="platform-btn-container">
                        <div class="link-btn"><i class="fas fa-play"></i>Stream</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="platform-click" value="spotify" />
                </div>
}
                @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Album.ItunesLink))
    {
                <div class="platform-list-item">
                    <div class="platform-logo-container">
                        <img class="platform-logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/unlink/platform-images/music-service_itunes_v2.svg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="platform-btn-container">
                        <div class="link-btn"><i class="fas fa-play"></i>Download</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="platform-click" value="itunes" />
                </div>
}
                @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Album.AppleMusicLink))
    {
                <div class="platform-list-item">
                    <div class="platform-logo-container">
                        <img class="platform-logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/unlink/platform-images/music-service_applemusic_v2.svg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="platform-btn-container">
                        <div class="link-btn"><i class="fas fa-play"></i>Stream</div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="platform-click" value="appleMusic" />
                </div>
}


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there authentication involved? Is your method hit?

Comment: @Stand__Sure no auth, and nothing is being printed to my debug console so it appears my JsonResult isn't being hit

Comment: You cannot redirect from AJAX, so the AJAX call is not being fired at all. You have another event (most likely a form submit) running before that.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If another event is running beforehand how can I detect the event? Nothing else is showing up in the network tab besides those two

Comment: That depends on what is `.platform-list-item`. Can you post the entire html/view code? Otherwise, to what line does it point to when you click on `VM89:1` on the 302 line in the posted image?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sure! I've posted it above for you. Also that line points to `n.apply(e, arguments)`

Comment: So my guess that it could be a submit button doesn't hold as it's a `<div>`... Any idea from where that `n.apply(e, arguments)` line comes from? It's a script that you register at some point

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto hmm so the thing is, I dont have a submit button on that page. It's not a script that I personally added, but maybe came with MVC? Here's a link to the script in jsfiddle, I've never seen something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2bxyjtpu/

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto also just tried to run the ajax on page load with the same error (just fyi)

Comment: What `<script>` tags do you have in that page? That fiddle looks like a compatibility library

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have: `jquery-1.10.2.js`, `modernizr-2.6.2.js` and `color-thief.js` (a js that helps calculate an average color of an image). Those are what is included on the current page according to the sources tab in Chrome! Just updated jquery to 3.3.1 no difference though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the `responseText` is my Home Index.cshtml page for some reason too

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto adding to my further confusion, IF `PlatformClick` JsonResult is in my AccountController AND I'm logged in, it works...but not in my original controller while logged in..